# Necessary Goods, Price Elasticity, Long-Term Calculations

Tags: reference-request, elasticity, energy-economics

My question is a conceptual one, though it arose from a concrete calculation that I'm working on. I'm looking at the economic viability of thermal retrofits, and [this author](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.enbuild.2012.03.043) suggests including the fuel price elasticity when calculating the net-present value that would result from performing a thermal retrofit.

Though the concept is clear, I have the following issue: the price elasticity of heating fuel is low (in the paper he calculates -0.476), which is to be expected since the good is a necessity. Nevertheless, it is not zero, and since fuel prices increase with time, and the technical lifetime of a retrofit is quite long, it is not inconceivable that due the price elasticity, the expected "demand" for the fuel falls below that which is necessary to heat a home. This led me to this idea that there was possibly a concept of elasticity that was price or quantity *dependent*, which would essentially capture the idea that elasticity would fall to zero as the quantity approached the minimum threshold for keeping the consumer's home warm.

Is this line of reasoning sensible?

If so, it would seem as though the "point-price elasticity of demand" is the concept that I need, but perhaps you guys have other ideas?

If something like the point-price elasticity is the correct concept, I would be grateful for a reference to demand functions that result in a non-constant price elasticity for a necessary good, as explained above. A linear function seems to work; are there other examples?

Comment: But the concept of (own price) elasticity IS of course price and quantity dependent. Constant elasticity demand functions are just a very special case. Any demand function which becomes vertical at some positive minimum quantity will have elasticity dropping to zero at this quantity.

Comment: @VARulle, thank you, that's helpful; a function of the form $P=A/(Q-Q_0)$ for constants $A$ and $Q_0$ seems to be what I'm looking for. If constant elasticity demand functions are the exception rather than the rule, why is it extremely rare to see elasticities denoted as being quantity or price dependent? (In the paper I cited, for instance.)

Comment: I think the reason is that elasticities are usually estimated at the current price, and for small deviations. If deviations are small enough, elasticity is roughly constant. It's analogous to estimating the slope of a nonlinear curve at some point and approximating the function locally by a line. (But that's a guess, I'm not an expert in this field...)